# Передать массив из одного класса в другой

Tags: objective-c, swift

Вопрос простой, и, по сути, я знаю, что делать, но что-то по-жесткачу туплю. Суть вот в чем.

У меня в основном классе ViewControllerе происоходят основные действия, и по ним заполняется массив строк. По нажатию кнопки я перехожу к другом ViewControllerу, который работает в качестве другого поля действий, и в нем мне нужен создающийся в первом controllere массив строк для дальнейшей работы.

Передаю я его таким образом: создаю класс в новом классе и вытаскиваю из него массив, но он пустой. Что я пропустил?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я вижу три варианта решения данной проблемы:

1. Singelton pattern. Если в одном контроллере был создан instance этого класса, то в другом при попытке создать новую копию того же класса, мы получим уже созданный в предыдущем контроллере класс со всеми его потрохами.
2. Если используется Storyboard, то в prepareForSegue можно передать этот массив напрямую контроллеру, на который идет переключение.
3. Delegate pattern. Создать делегат, через который и будет происходить коммуникация между контроллерами.

Answer (score 0):

> создаю класс в новом классе и вытаскиваю из него массив, но он пустой

Нужно между *создаю класс в новом классе* и *вытаскиваю из него массив* наполнить его (класса) массив данными.

Answer (score 0):

Во втором классе по жесткачу ;) нужно создать проперти массива (желательно мутабельный) в хидер-файле (не в инкапсуляции), и потом:

```
SecondViewController *secVC = [SecondViewController new];
secVC.massivCopy = [self.massivOriginal mutableCopy];
```

Есть и другие способы передачи, более рациональные.